# Opened unity and my whole scene is broken

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I open unity to find that half of my scene is missing and a bunch of random errors in the console such as Broken text PPtr in file(Assets/Scenes/Main.unity). Local file identifier (buncha random numbers) doesn't exist!

Theres a ton of those

and Transform component could not be found on game object 'Cylinder (1)'. Adding one.

I can't figure this out and really need my scene back I have tried trying to get the scene from the apk file build but I wasn't successful as I have not clue if it is even possible.

Comment: The same happened to me so I just gave up and uninstalled Unity. The unreal engine was too hard to learn. Did you use repository for your project. You could checkout your latest version.

Comment: **Pro tip:** 1) always use source control 2) upgrading Unity is _always_ a breaking change so check-in your source code before hand  3) try exiting Unity, deleting the **Library** folder and re-opening your project.  4) Failing that, perform step 3 as well as reverting local changes in source control. 
 https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to remake some things but this is a lesson to always backup your projects! I also now just open a useless scene before exiting in case this happens again as all my other scenes were fine.